# Strictly RAW, is punching someone with a crossbow a melee attack with a ranged weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, rogue, paladin, improvised-weaponry

I’m exploring ways to combine the Crusher feat with a melee rogue-paladin, and have come into a conundrum- without using my busy bonus action to two-weapon-fight with a club, is there a way to get bludgeoning damage with a melee rogue?

This is my best attempt- using Tavern Brawler to punch people with a crossbow as the strangest of Improvised Weapons. As this is just a rules exploration unlikely to see the light of day, RAI isn’t very relevant here.

RAW, will punching someone with a crossbow allow it to be a melee weapon attack with a ranged weapon, letting me use sneak attack and smite?

Unlike questions regarding thrown improvised weapons which, outside of being improvised weapons, notably lack the finesse or ranged properties, crossbows clearly have the ranged property. This question isn’t about if improvised weapons give it a new property, but rather, if they retain their original property (in this case, ranged).

Comment: I’ve closed your question as a duplicate, let us know if that doesn’t answer your question and why, and we’ll get it reopened.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I’ve put a clarification edit on how it doesn’t- I’m not asking if being an improvised weapon allows it to be used with sneak attack (crossbows definitely can be used with sneak attack)- I’m asking if you can still sneak attack with ranged weapons when using them as improvised weapons, or if by being an improvised weapon they LOSE the ranged/finesse traits.

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139907/raw-can-you-use-the-sharpshooter-and-great-weapon-master-feats-to-make-an-impro?noredirect=1&lq=1 is also a relevant duplicate for the other part of the question.

Comment: I added a second duplicate target, and while it isn't asking precisely the same thing, do you (Abigale Moore) feel it answers your question? In particular the highest-scoring answer asserts that improvised weapons are neither melee nor ranged weapons

Comment: The "If using a weapon as an improvised weapon, are any of its properties retained?" question best answered it, in that the weapon is no longer a ranged weapon, but I appreciate the help!